# Castor - MappingException Java class not constructable

Tags: java, castor

Using Castor 1.3, received the following exception while testing:

```
org.exolab.castor.mapping.MappingException: The Java class com.company.sales.app.valueobjects.eai.ContactInformationValueObject$CommunicationPreference is not constructable -- it does not contain a default public constructor
```

Attempting to use a collection of a public inner class in my Java code.

**Class examples**:

```
public class Car {
   public String color;
   public String make;
   public String model;
   public List<RoadTrip> roadTrips;

   public class RoadTrip {
      public String pointA;
      public String pointB;
   }
}
```

**XML Mapping**:

```
<class name="com.auto.Car" >
    <field name="color" type="java.lang.String"><bind-xml name="COLOR" /></field>
    <field name="make" type="java.lang.String"><bind-xml name="MAKE" /></field>
    <field name="model" type="java.lang.String"><bind-xml name="MODEL" /></field>
    <field name="roadTrips" type="com.auto.Car$RoadTrip"><bind-xml name="TRIP" /></field>
</class>
<class name="com.auto.Car$RoadTrip">
    <field name="pointA" type="java.lang.String"><bind-xml name="STARTING_POINT" /></field>
    <field name="pointB" type="java.lang.String"><bind-xml name="DESTINATION" /></field>
</class>
```

**XML Example**

```
<AUTOMOBILE>
    <COLOR>LITTLE RED</COLOR>
    <MAKE>CHEVROLET</MAKE>
    <MODEL>CORVETTE</MODEL>
    <TRIP>
        <STARTING_POINT>DALLAS</STARTING_POINT>
        <DESTINATION>VEGAS</DESTINATION>
    </TRIP>
    <TRIP>
        <STARTING_POINT>SEATTLE</STARTING_POINT>
        <DESTINATION>PORTLAND</DESTINATION>
    </TRIP>
</AUTOMOBILE>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Reason I was getting the exception is because I needed to make my inner class Static for Castor to be able to work with it.

There are quite a few posts elsewhere around the web that suggest using the

```
verify-constructable="false"
```

but missing static on the inner class was a simple mistake. Hope it helps someone else!

```
public class Car {
   public String color;
   public String make;
   public String model;
   public List<RoadTrip> roadTrips;

   public static class RoadTrip {
      public String pointA;
      public String pointB;
   }
}
```

http://castor.codehaus.org/1.2/how-to-map-an-inner-class.html